# My jquery validate error message doesn't show in red, is my error missing built in styling?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-validate

I'm using jquery validate to validate 3 attributes (minlength, maxlength, required) in the element.

```
<input id="jumbotronSearch" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Location" required maxlength="50" minlength="4"/>
```

But when the error message is displayed it displays it in black, not red.

From seeing other threads and sites that demo and display validation error messages it seems like the message should be in red and the border of the element will be red too!?? Do I have to style this myself or am I missing some file or a configuration parameter for jquery validate to ge tit to show in red?

Here is what the error message looks like, see the message is black, not red and the border of the element isn't red!

[image]

Comment: There are NO stylesheets included with this plugin.  If it's red, it has nothing to do with jQuery Validate.

Comment: Check that your validation.js file is above the js file you are using to do the error checking, if this is in a seperate file. I had a similar issue where my js file in question validating a form on a particular page was above the validation.js file and so it threw me off a bit, with other validation error logs being highlighted in red, whilst this one wasn't. I simply moved up the js file doing the error handling below validation.js file and it worked! Hope this helps someone else too.

Answer (score 1):

> ... it seems like the message should be in red and the border of the element will be red too!?? Do I have to style this myself...

**Yes**, since the plugin does not include a CSS stylesheet, you have to style this yourself.

By default, this plugin applies a class called `error` to the invalid element and its message label, and a class called `valid` to the validated element.

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/06cLoL8c/](https://jsfiddle.net/06cLoL8c/)**

A quick glance at the official website and you can see there are no CSS files included:

[jqueryvalidation.org](https://jqueryvalidation.org)

> From seeing other threads and sites that demo and display validation error messages it seems like the message should be in red...

These other people are likely using frameworks such as Bootstrap, which may include CSS that already targets `.error` and `.valid` classes.  Otherwise, you can use the `validClass` and `errorClass` options to rename these classes into anything you wish.

Here is the same demo as above, but with ridiculous styling applied in the CSS:

[jsfiddle.net/y06ur48o/](https://jsfiddle.net/y06ur48o/)

You should read the documentation for all available plugin options:  [jqueryvalidation.org/validate/](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)

Comment: @user1186050, I don't know.  Why not read the documentation I linked to and match up the classes accordingly?

Comment: I don't believe the effect I'm seeking (mostly the highlighting of the border with red) comes from bootstrap. I'm pretty sure it comes from some type of validation action.

Comment: @user1186050, the validation plugin does **not** come with CSS... it merely adds/removes the `error` and `valid` classes.  Period.  If you believe otherwise, merely [inspect the code](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/jquery.validate.js) to confirm the fact.